# How to make the div height dynamic

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

How to make the div height dynamic so that it increases the height automatically when data inserted exceed the size of div?

```
<div class="group"style="background:white;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #DDDADA;">
          <div class="cadetabox" id="s10">
            <div class="capht"><img src="images/user_picture.jpg" width="50" height="50"/></div>
            <div class="caphtdtail">
          <a href="CADetail.php"><h4>CA Ritesh </h4></a>
              <p> learn how to setup video calls learn how to setup video calls learn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video calls Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai </p>
              <p>2 yrs Experience</p>
              <p style="color: green;">Open Today</p>
            </div>
                     <a href="login-register.php"><span class="likespan"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: 18px;"></i> 0</span></a>
                      <a href="#"><span class="span" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Call</span></a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Frame your question properly.

Comment: the height of div is not increasing when I insert the data which is more than the size of div.

Comment: you need to use `height:auto` on your div.. And look at the question posted.. you have not formatted the question properly..  Also you have placed your question as title. I will update your post..

Comment: Can i use display:-webkit-flex ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS `height` property to make the div height dynamic.

Use `height:auto;` **[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_height)**

And here is a sample of your code.

```css
.caphtdtail {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="group" style="background:white;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #DDDADA;">
  <div class="cadetabox" id="s10">
    <div class="capht">
      <img src="images/user_picture.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="caphtdtail">
      <a href="CADetail.php"><h4>CA Ritesh </h4></a>
      <p>learn how to setup video calls learn how to setup video calls learn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video callslearn how to setup video calls Kandivali,
        Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai Kandivali, Mumbai</p>
      <p>2 yrs Experience</p>
      <p style="color: green;">Open Today</p>
    </div>
    <a href="login-register.php"><span class="likespan"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size: 18px;"></i> 0</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="span" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Call</span></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```